# Monster hunter/ traveler silver weapons?

Tags: weapons

In my own research I have concluded that bows are usually the preferred weapon for a hunter of monsters. But in universe the most reliable way of hurting monsters are silver, and silver arrows can get costly. Originally I thought of using the Witcher way and have a sword made of steel and have the edges covered in silver. But swords make for rather horrible hunting weapons. And the weapons have to be viable against humans too. As hunters usually drifts from place to place, they need to be able to defend against humans who might attack them while traveling.

Monsters in this context refers to anything from undead (zombies, Ghouls, etc) to trolls and giants to wildlife cursed with immortality. Monsters are a rare sight where humans live preferring to keep to the "old" parts of the world.
Monster hunters are themselves usually inhuman (half any kind of spiritual being. Example: devil, angel, fey) and are therefore shunned and payed poorly for anything. A lot of hunters prefer to travel to get work too. So they need to carry most if not all of their equipment with them.

So in this case what would be one or two all-purpose weapons a Monster hunter could carry?

Comment: There is no question mark in this question.

Comment: I concur; while I *think* I know what the OP is asking for, he doesn't explicitly say.

Answer (score 4):

**Spear**

If you're looking for an all-purpose weapon that can be used against monsters and humans and doesn't cost a fortune in silver, then you want a spear of some kind. It's longer range makes it a better choice for fighting monsters, it can be thrown in a pinch (or you can carry javelin in addition) and it's a very viable choice against human opponents, not to mention that the metal spear head is cheaper than outfitting a full sword. I'd suggest looking into a boar spear particularly if you want to extra effective against charging monsters.

Answer (score 2):

"But swords make for rather horrible hunting weapons"

Actually I'd argue no weapon is ever good or bad except in context.
A sword is an excellent weapon against unarmored humans and is a excellent side arm and a backup.

Spears, the most dominant weapon in ancient battlefields as we all know, are also excellent but as history shown us actual strategy can reduce the efficiency of a particular unit, notice unit and not weapon, and weaken the moral of it as well so that it's spears are pretty useless.

So the idea of good or bad loses all meaning here as we have **no** idea what monsters are being hunted and what are their characteristics are.

For example fighting in medieval town against vampires I'd suggest something like a sword. As their skin is not armored and a cut is deadly enough, silver swords, as well as the fact you are limited in space.

But say you go after a big thick skinned animal that you don't want to get close to, even spears won't help. Better use bows or crossbows. Heck. Use mounted artillery, like the scorpion, or trap it or do something that does **not** involve  getting close.

So I have to say we need to know more about the world and monsters.

Also it seems that the idea of expensive silver is kind of an odd point in a world where monsters exist and a profession of hunting them exits.
Won't that mean that the demand on silver weapons increases leading to more people trying to make them and, as history shown us, with enough time an overall decrease in the prices?
Like computers or smartphones.

In fact I do remember reading that at certain places in history swords started becoming widespread sidearms and became cheap as a result.

And how and why would monster hunters continue existing while they are so poor to the point of not affording a couple of decent weapons?
I'm not saying it's impossible or that it's stupid. But rather there most be enough coin in it, you know the type that is tossed to the witcher, to at least continue their trade with the needed tools.

Now in history poor knights, or men at arms really, and such things are real.
But again those people are hunting monsters, can't they raise enough money for the basic stuff?
Heck. What about loot? I know that in video games things are littered all around.
But there is a grain of truth in that.

That is that the dragon's lair is full of treasure. Now that might not be the case in your world but they should at least run into a good contract or kill a monster that is hoarding a small treasure or even that had others try to hunt it and failed so you can loot them.

I mean honestly what's the point of having a witcher...er monster hunter that does go around looting stuff and having fun?

But like I said we don't know the full context so providing us with more details can explain why those things are true and what is going on.

**Update**.

Ok in that case here is my combo.
Spear, sword, and shield.
Now a sword is a good all round backup weapon that was always used if you can afford it.

However those people are alone so fighting humans in towns or defending themselves against monsters that ambush them...etc
is important. So I say give them even a simple arming sword as a sidearm.

Spear and shield combo is pretty obvious.
Range and protection and all that.
But I will also suggest something a little more expensive, more on that later, so that they get the best out of this.

Full metal shields are rare. But what is historical is a thin layer of metal on shields. This is as old as the Greek, and even older but that's what I read so yeah, and so a thin layer of silver on the shield will add durability but also lethality against monsters.

The spear obviously will need to have a silver coated head. But I also suggesting adding silver coated langets to the whole of the shaft so that it's deadly to the touch. Again monsters are the game here and you want to give yourself every advantage possible. So a langet will make the shaft more durable but also make it an actual weapon against monsters.

I did not mention bows because you need arrows and it seems to me that a lone bowman against a deadly monster is a bad idea. Actual hunting is about loosing a well aimed arrow against non deadly stuff. And the deadly stuff are hunted in a different way.
But anyway it seems like your characters are already inhuman so what do they care if they get close!
So forgetting arrows makes more sense I'd say.

However a crossbow can be very useful. And if you have a 2-3 man monster hunter then they can construct a single manned very portable scorpion to act as a machine gun of sorts.

Halberds, warhammers, glaive...etc.

Now you can argue them for example a pointed warhammer against a thick skinned monster, much like knight and armor, but then you said you want versatile weapons that are the ancient equivalent to automatic rifles.

And that is the spear, shield, and sword load out. Bows are up there as well. So trying to create a very long 2 man used spear is useless because you only got one man.

Phalanx type super long spears are also useless as even if you can operate it alone how will you travel with it? And it's very unpractical in single combat. So again we are looking for something that is a jack of all trades and that's what I, and most people here, said already.

Now to the other problem. Logistics.

Well here is a problem. The monsters are in certain places and strong enough that creates an actual problem!

Now this is pure economy. I might despise the witcher that rolled into town but that monster is slowly killing **all** the livestock in
our little town. And you already said they are in remote places so it's less likely that the local lord would care.
So no matter how much I hate him I have to ask him to go hunt the monster. It's pure survival at this point.
Now unless the witcher is an idiot he can name any payable price.
Heck. He can ask for the money upfront or at least a large enough installment to insure they have the rest.
And when he returns with 3 troll heads I doubt that farmers will deny him pay.

Remember that famous part when Geralt was welcomed into the inn with the song? Life is not that different. A good song or a very nice service to people can change opinions. So the eternally despised and hated monster hunters are not always the most realistic. Of course you might do things in a different way or have reasons. I'd just say that at this point is "politics"

So this is pure economics.
If people need this service and you are the only one to provide it then you can charge any price. Now there are limitation, and obviously people can only pay so much, but generally speaking when there is such a strong compelling need for people they will pay.

Not to mention that what I said about monsters and treasures still stands.

I'd also add that silver should be incorporated into the monster hunters clothing as will as even the horse armor.

I'd also suggest silver lassos, silver bombs, silver traps...etc.
Imagine a barrel of silver dust that you lead a big strong monster to wall below and let it fall down on the thing.

Just silver stuff all around and have you monster hunters kill those things is artistic and creative ways.

Lastly. I'm not sure I said anything groundbreaking really.

Comment: Hope that helped a bit. I'm rather new to posting on forums.

Comment: @RexO,
I updated the answer.
Welcome. I hope you have a good time

Answer (score 2):

**Silver ring.**

It is crap as a weapon.  You have to close with the monster and you have to hit it with a solid left.  So you had better have something in your right hand - a rake or a net or something.  Hopefully you have something protecting your face too.

But if you can land that punch, the monster is toast.  The ring is silver but more than that, as sometimes these rings are.

I present this idea because as you note: Witcher has been done, Monster Hunter has been done.  Done done done.  But monster fisticuffs with a special ring, not so much.

Answer (score 2):

**Silver Caltrops**

With monsters, you aren't hunting them as much as them hunting you. With silver caltrops you can bait them to attack and when they charge, they step on the caltrops breaking the charge and possibly fall onto more caltrops. The caltrops can be collected after you've slain the monster

**Polearm**

[image]

A polearm is used to break a charge. You set the pole arm and allow the monster to charge into it. Pole arms usually have arms to stop the target from pushing forward. It also allows you to fight out of range because most monsters you don't want to get close because the monster is usually stronger, faster and is capable of tearing you to shreds.

**Crossbow**

A crossbow can be loaded ready to fire so it's just point and fire giving you much faster reaction time. A bow needs to be drawn before it can be fired so is slower

**Dagger**

When everything has gone to hell and the monster has closed on you, you don't have the room to use a sword or a spear. A dagger is a last ditch weapon you can draw from your belt to defend yourself

**Bayonet**

[image]

Adding the dagger to the crossbow as a bayonet means you're still armed after firing the bolt